# Is there a way I can elegantly color my chess-piece squares with just CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid-container with 64 grid-items. It's meant to represent a chess-board and it's arranged like so:

Never mind that the pieces are upside down - concentrate on the color of the squares and the grid-items - numbered in their appearance in source-order.
[image]

The task is to color the squares like this picture. Here's some pseudo-code of how I achieved this with js:

```js
let arrayOfSquares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.board-grid-container > div`)); 
        for (let index = 0, total = 1; index <= 63; total++) {
            arrayOfSquares[index].classList.add(`black-square`);
            if (total === 4) {
                index = index + 3;
            } else if (total === 8) {
                index = index + 1;
                total = 0;
            } else {
                index = index + 2;
            }
        }
```

My question is, could I have done this elegantly with CSS? The only way I could think of was to do something like this:

```css
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+8):nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+9):nth-child(-n+15):nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: white;
}
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+18):nth-child(-n+24):nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+25):nth-child(-n+31):nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: white;
}
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+34):nth-child(-n+40):nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+41):nth-child(-n+47):nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: white;
}
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+50):nth-child(-n+56):nth-child(even) {
    background-color: white;
}
.board-grid-container > div:nth-child(n+57):nth-child(-n+63):nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Why not make the squares transparent and put a background on the grid container itself like so: https://jsfiddle.net/gztj1ecq/

Comment: @Blackhole The answer to the question does have a more elegant CSS solution - I would like to mark that it does answer the question (if you could ask the question of me again, sorry I responded 'no' the first time).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir that looks great. Any good learning resources you could pass on that explain using `linear-gradient` as a value to `background-image` property?

Comment: MDN article on `linear-gradient`: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()), CSS-Tricks articles on all the gradients: [here](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-gradients/) and the background I showed you is using multiple backgrounds (2 linear gradients at once, each draws a triangle and the two triangles makes up the squares), [here](https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-multiple-backgrounds/) is how that works

Comment: and here are some crazy stuff that you can do with just gradients: https://projects.verou.me/css3patterns/